# £ symbol not beind Read from TXT file in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

When i run my program to open a txt file, it doesnt display the £ symbol. Is there a way to display it? Heres my code

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Imports System.Text

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim path As String = ("H:\16.1\Stock.txt")
        ' Open the file to read from.
        Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim Z As String
        For Each Z In readText
            Console.WriteLine(Z)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you confirm the character encoding of your text file, i.e. that it is actually UTF8?

Comment: yes i have @RobertColumbia

Comment: The console doesn't display UTF-8 text by default. It takes a lot of extra effort. I'll bet the symbol is being read correctly. Use the debugger to ensure that it's there in the string, as expected. Consider outputting to a text file, instead.

Comment: Could you show us the contents of the text file and what the program actually outputs?

Comment: I've just remade the text file and saved it as UTF8 encoding and now it works - Many Thanks